# PC wakes up automatically only for a few minutes(I need more time)

Tags: jenkins, window

I set up Jenkins to run some jobs(It runs 10 minutes) at night. In that time PC is already went sleep. Thats why i set up Task Scheduler:
Triggered every days. Actions cmd.exe/c"exit". This think wake up PC only for two minutes, but i need 10(and more in the future). Do you mind helping me solve this problem?

Comment: might wanna post this on https://superuser.com/ instead

Comment: Thank you for advice. Is it unacceptable to post question like this ?